# Rewrite URL for WordPress with htaccess for multiple query string parameters

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, web

Our main site is on WordPress. We have external links coming in with various query string parameters. Unfortunately, some of these interfere with WordPress (e.g. 's' is reserved).

I would like to setup rewrite rules with htaccess since that is how I am already doing some things for the site. My issue is that I need to REPLACE the query string parameters with new names so they are not conflicting.

Possible Parameters and Mapping:

```
'l' -> 'li'
's' -> 'si'
'g' -> 'gi'
'i' -> 'ii'
```

These can come in any order but basically need to be replaced with the above mapping. An example:

FROM
http://www.domain.com/register?l=something&s=something (order not predictable)

TO
http://www.domain.com/register?li=something&si=something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your htaccess file **before** any rules you already have, add these:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1si=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?l=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1li=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?g=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1gi=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?i=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1ii=%2 [L]
```

Comment: I think this is very close. The issue I am having now is it seems to be matching other query string parameters that end in one of the letters above ('s', 'l', 'g', 'i').